# FutureBuilder: run future only when ExpansionTile is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```dart
ExpansionTile(
  maintainState: true,
  children: [
    FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: ...
    )
  ]
)
```

The default behavior is building all the widgets together. I would like to first build the `ExpansionTile`, and then, on `ExpansionTile` expanded, build the `FutureBuilder` calling `_future`.

**EDIT 1**

```dart
ExpansionTile(
                                        maintainState: true,
                                        expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        onExpansionChanged: (value){
                                          setState(() {
                                            isExpanded = value;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        
                                       
                                        children: [
 
                                          Builder(
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              if(isExpanded){
                                                return FutureBuilder(
                                                    future: _future
                                                    builder: (),
                                                );
                                              }
                                              return SizedBox();
                                            },
                                          )
 
                                          
 
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

Comment: for this, you must use the state manager like bloc or getX or etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my thinking the FutureBuilder is very dumb Widget as it rebuild it self on every state change.
Still, i found a work around for your issue.

you refer to the below code:

```
  dynamic futureFunction;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text('Title'),
          childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              futureFunction = value ? _future() : null;
            });
          },
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<String>(
              future: futureFunction,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                futureFunction = null;
                // your operations and returning widget.
                return Text(snapshot.data ?? 'Loading');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> _future() async {
    print('inside _future()');
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    return 'Working';
  }
```

Here i have taken a dynamic variable 'futureFun' that will have null or the future function itself and given to the FutureBuilder future property(FutureBuilder don't build itself if you pass null to the future property).

Firstly, it will be null then if you expand the expansionTile it will be assigned with the future function, and after the performing your operations in the futureBuilder you can make it null so it doesn't rebuild on every setState.

Comment: Always returning "Loading" and not "Working"

Comment: FYI the questioner wanted 'working'. now he/she update and removed that part

Answer (score 1):

You can, pseudo code that goes along with your code

```
ExpansionTile(
  maintainState: true,
  children: [
    Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // check if your expansion tile is expanded
       // if expanded 
           return  FutureBuilder(
                     future: _future,
                     builder: ...
        );
      // if not expanded, return anything you want like empty 
          return SizedBox();
    },
  ]
)
```

**Updated Code:** You may need to adjust it as per your needs,specially calling setState expanded below or above the Future.delayed function.`main.dart` file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});    
  final String title;    
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  dynamic futureFunction;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text('Title'),
          childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              futureFunction = value ? _future() : null;
            });
          },
          children: [
            Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if (isExpanded) {
                  return FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: futureFunction,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      futureFunction = null;
                      // your operations and returning widget.
                      return Text(snapshot.data ?? 'Loading');
                    },
                  );
                }
                return SizedBox();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> _future() async {
    print('inside _future()');
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    setState(() {
      isExpanded = true;
    });
    return 'Working';
  }
}
```

Comment: always returning SizedBox().

Comment: Can you provide more code or explain how are you checking your expansion title state?
How is your Future Builder implemented?

Comment: of course https://pastebin.com/0WRKRZDw . I think `isExpanded` is updated when the Builder is already built

Comment: I am unable to access the link. It says This site can’t be reached.

Comment: Added code to the question

Comment: tried the same code but still showing SizedBox

Comment: It seems something is preventing state update. I will need minimal code to reproduce this issue, because my code is working fine, implying something missing from your code.
If you can provide the minimal code to reproduce this issue, it will help a lot.
Thanks :)

Comment: I have also added the full code which works. You can try running it and compare it with your code.

Comment: you are right, the code's working. I'll have to find were my code breaks, because in my complex implementation isn't working. Thanks anyway!